# Jquery next selector next() question

Tags: jquery

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| this is div .content                                                 |
|                                                                      |
|              +----------------+                                      |
|              | .left_content  |                                      | 
|              | input inside   |                                      |             
|              +----------------+                                      |
|                                                                      |
|                                                                      |
|                                                      +------------+  |
|                                                      |     span   |  |
|                                                      +------------+  |
|                                                                      |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Hello all, I'm trying to access the span element with jquery but I have some kind of error, here is the deal `.content` is main div , `.left_content` div is inside it and `span` is inside `.content` but outside `.left_content`.

Now I can easily access `span` by using `.content span`, but since .content, .left_content and span are repeating throughout the website I want to access these elements by clicking on the `input inside .left_content div`.

So finally I come to my question (from input inside .left_content perspective), how to get div `.content` , `.left_content` and `span` selected?

So far what I've only managed to do is to get `.left_content` selector by using `$(this)parent('div:first')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
$(this).closest("div.content").find("span")
```

Comment: Both solutions work I'll accept your answer because its shorter

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean, but:

```
$('input').click(function() {
    var left_content = $(this).parent();
    var content = left_content.parent();
    var span = content.find('span');
});
```